# 2d array, print maze, C

Tags: arrays, c, 2d, maze

I don't know how to print generated maze in 2d array. There are following functions:

```
struct maze {
  char **a;               // 2D array supporting maze
  unsigned int w;         // width
  unsigned int h;         // height
  unsigned int cell_size; // number of chars per cell; walls are 1 char
};
```

and the one generating it ends with `return maze`;

```
struct maze generate_maze(unsigned int width, unsigned int height,
                          unsigned int cell_size, int rand_seed) {
  int row, col, i;
  struct stack stack;
  struct cell cell;
  struct cell neighbours[4]; // to hold neighbours of a cell
  int num_neighbs;
  struct maze maze;
  maze.w = width;
  maze.h = height;
  maze.cell_size = cell_size;
  maze.a =
      (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * maze_dimension_to_matrix(&maze, height));

  // Initialise RNG
  srand(rand_seed);

  // Initialise stack
  init_stack(&stack, width * height);

  return maze;
}
```

I have to write the main function taking input to generate maze and print it. So far I have this:

```
int main() {
  int height;
  int width;
  int cellSizer;
  int randSeed;

  printf("enter Height ");
  scanf("%d", &height);
  printf("enter Width ");
  scanf("%d", &width);
  printf("enter Seed ");
  scanf("%d", &randSeed);
  printf("enter cellSizer ");
  scanf("%d", &cellSizer);
  printf("%d %d %d %d \n", height, width, cellSizer, randSeed);

  struct maze test = generate_maze(width, height, cellSizer, randSeed);

  int row, col;

  for (row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < width; col++) {
      maze.a[height][width];
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
  for (row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    for (col = 0; col < width; col++) {
      printf("%c", maze.a[height][width]);
      If(height = width) printf("/n");
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know how to progress, I know to print the 2d array I have to call an array which is `maze.a` but I'm getting an `error: 'maze' undeclared(first use in the function)` How can I fix my code so it will print the maze?

Comment: You called your maze `test`, so you should use `test.a`

Comment: Please include *all* of your code in the question. Right now there are several undeclared functions: `maze_dimension_to_matrix`, `init_stack` which means we are not able to reproduce your errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I sort it out:

```
struct maze maze = generate_maze(width, heigh, cellSizer, randomSeed);
for(row=0; row < maze.h; row++){
            for(col=0; col < maze.w; col++){
                printf("%c", maze.a[row][col]);

            }
           printf("\n");
        }
```